# Convert itouch mp4 to ipod video mp4 with Linux

Tags: linux, video, iphone, conversion, ipod

Anyone know how I can convert mp4 files meant for the iphone/itouch to a a video files that will work on a regular ipod that supports video with Linux.

Command line would be better, multicore support would be good too.

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: ~quack: I honestly don't know, iTunes says the ipod can't play it and wants to convert it.  Converting the files on one of my Linux machines would probably be a lot faster.

Comment: if you look up the specific models on http://support.apple.com/specs/# you may find why the video needs to be re-encoded

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php).

> HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.

Moreover, it has built-in presets for iPod and iPhone and it could be used with a GUI or a CLI.

Comment: Tried with the universal preset and the result didn't work either.  Ran out of time, next time I will have a go at sal's answer, and hte ipod preset in handbrake.

Answer (score 1):

I installed ffmpeg, libfaad, libfaac and x264 and have been using this command

```
ffmpeg -i "file.avi" -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -s 640x480 -vcodec libx264 -vpre hq -vpre ipod640 -threads 0 -f ipod "file.m4v"
```

I build ffmpeg this way

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
make all
```

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg is probably the best free video converter out there.

http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) has some presets built in for Apple products:

> Avidemux is a free video editor
> designed for simple cutting, filtering
> and encoding tasks. It supports many
> file types, including AVI, DVD
> compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF,
> using a variety of codecs. Tasks can
> be automated using projects, job queue
> and powerful scripting capabilities.
>
> Avidemux is available for Linux, BSD,
> Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows under
> the GNU GPL license. The program was
> written from scratch by Mean, but code
> from other people and projects has
> been used as well. Patches,
> translations and even bug reports are
> always welcome.